# What is the idempotent $e_\chi$ associated to a character $\chi$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, characters

Suppose $\chi\colon G\to k^\times$ is an (irreducible) character of a finite group $G$ into a field $k$. What is the definition of the corresponding idempotent $e_\chi$?

I know that over $\mathbb{C}$, the corresponding central idempotent is
$$
e_\chi=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\overline{\chi(g)}g.
$$

If we don't have a notion of conjugation, is the corresponding idempotent just
$$
\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)^{-1}g?
$$

Comment: What means $\chi(g_1)^{-1}g_1+\chi(g_2)^{-1}g_2$ ? Are you considering $G$ as a subgroup of $GL_n(k)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: it's an element of the group algebra $k[G]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

$$\frac{\chi(1)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^{-1}) g.$$

Note that $\chi(g)$ is not always invertible, and if it is, its inverse is usually not its conjugate. But $\chi(g^{-1}) = \overline{\chi(g)}$ if $k$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ closed under complex conjugation.

Comment: (The comment about $\chi(g)$ not being invertible or its inverse not equaling its conjugate applies with characters of complex representations of dimension greater than one, in which case the normalization constant is $\dim/|G|$ instead of just $1/|G|$ for the isotypical projector.)

Comment: Thanks! I should have specified my $\chi$ is a multiplicative character, in which case our elements are the same? But I suspect your answer works for the general case of any character of a representation, not just multiplicative/linear ones?

Comment: @Camilla: yes, I assumed this is the case you were interested in because you mentioned irreducible characters.

Answer (score 2):

There is a different definition over $\mathbb{C}$ for the projector onto the irreducible representation $V$, which is
$$\psi_V = \frac{\dim V}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_V(g) g^{-1}$$

I believe this definition extends to any field $k$ whose characteristic does not divide $|G|$.

Comment: Does $k$ need $m$th roots of unity, where $m$ is the exponent of $G$?

Comment: What do you mean by the exponent of $G$? I don't think you need to say anything about having particular roots of unity.

Comment: It's quite easy to google "exponent of a group." Anyway, you're right - I checked the proof I know and the formula for isotypical projectors only uses division by $|G|$.